# Can I perform consecutive changes on resource with Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Sometimes I need to perform several changes to the resource with TF ( within same declaration file ) , for example:

1. Create Azure VNET/Subnet A
2. Create Private Endpoint
3. Change properties of Subnet A from #1

I tried to create same resource with *depends_on* statement, but it doesn't work.

```
module.vnet-stage2[1].azurerm_virtual_network.vnet: Creating...
module.vnet-stage2[0].azurerm_virtual_network.vnet: Creating...
╷
│ Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/6fd2b24c-1ffa-43ca-abc1-8127c30dcb39/resourceGroups/PE-TF-RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/client-vnet" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_virtual_network" for more information.
│
│   with module.vnet-stage2[0].azurerm_virtual_network.vnet,
│   on ../../modules/vnet/main.tf line 6, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet":
│    6: resource azurerm_virtual_network "vnet" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/6fd2b24c-1ffa-43ca-abc1-8127c30dcb39/resourceGroups/PE-TF-RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/server-vnet" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_virtual_network" for more information.
│
│   with module.vnet-stage2[1].azurerm_virtual_network.vnet,
│   on ../../modules/vnet/main.tf line 6, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet":
│    6: resource azurerm_virtual_network "vnet" {
│
╵
```

Comment: "I tried to create same resource with depends_on statement, but it doesn't work." - this is not specific. What is the exact code you "tried"? Why it does not work? Any errors?

Comment: Marcin, thank you for the question. I tried to define the same resource with subnet properties changed , depends_on the intermediary resource creation ( PE ) . The error I've got is on original question.

Comment: What is the code that generates the error?

Comment: I'm using https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Azure/vnet/azurerm/latest module for VNET ( for original and modification). However I believe the issue lies within "A resource with the ID XXX already exists" May be terraform just does not support consecutive changes ? Or I have to take different approach (not to modify/create same resource ) ?

Comment: Sadly its not clear know o you use the modlue. What modifications are you introducing?

Comment: I'm changing the following property of the subnet : subnet_enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies - originally setting it to False and , after PE creation , I'm looking to change it to True.

Comment: I mean, can you update the question with actual code example? In other words, how can anyone reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Andy, are you trying to create the same resource which is already present on azure(not created by terraform/stored in different state file)?as per the error it seems the vnet's you are trying to create are already present on azure but were not created from terraform. If that is the case then you need import the resources into state that you need to apply changes from terraform and then do the changes.

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT, thank you for replying. I'm trying to achieve the following : Create VNET + Subnet, Create Private Endpoint , Change property of the Subnet . To note, I'm trying to understand if I can do it in the same declaration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried testing your requirement with the below code. It's not possible to change the subnet `enforce_private_link_service_network_policies = true` to `false` from the same declaration file.

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features{}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "yourresourcegroup"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "service" {
  name                 = "service"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

  enforce_private_link_service_network_policies = true
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "endpoint" {
  name                 = "endpoint"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]

  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = true
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "example-pip"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
}


resource "azurerm_lb" "example" {
  name                = "example-lb"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = azurerm_public_ip.example.name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_link_service" "example" {
  name                = "example-privatelink"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  nat_ip_configuration {
    name      = azurerm_public_ip.example.name
    primary   = true
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.service.id
  }

  load_balancer_frontend_ip_configuration_ids = [
    azurerm_lb.example.frontend_ip_configuration.0.id,
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "example-endpoint"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.endpoint.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "example-privateserviceconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_private_link_service.example.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

When you try to change the value to false, you get the below error:

[image]

**Solution:**

You can create `Vnet+Subnet` first on file and then create private endpoint in another using data sources of the vnet and subnet. After private endpoint is created you can change the properties of subnet by going to the `vnet+subnet` file.

Or

You can create everything at once then use PowerShell or CLI to change that property of subnet.

**Command for CLI:**

```
az network vnet subnet update --disable-private-endpoint-network-policies false --name service --resource-group resourcegroup --vnet-name example-network.
```

**Reference:**

[Manage network policies for private endpoints - Azure Private Link | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/disable-private-endpoint-network-policy)

**Note:** `enforce_private_link_service_network_policies = true` on a subnet is mandatory for creating a private endpoint. After creation you can change to `enforce_private_link_service_network_policies = false`.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/) may be reviewed.